# How to get inverse map for a $S^{1}-\{(1,0)\} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functions

The given map is
\begin{align}
f : S^{1}-\{(1,0)\} &\to \mathbb{R} \\
   (x,y) &\mapsto \frac{y}{1-x}
\end{align}

${(x,y)} \in S^1-\{(1,0)\}$. How, do I calculate the inverse function $f^{-1}$. I know how to calculate the inverse for single variable functions. I also looked up the web, couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: If it lies on the unit circle, then you can just take $y=\pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks @CameronWilliams

Comment: Happy to help! $\,$

Answer (score 0):

We want a function $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow S^1\setminus \{(1,0)\}$ such that $f\circ g =\rm id$ and $g\circ f= \rm id $.

Now suppose you have $g(t)=(g_1(t),g_2(t))$; then it must be by $g\circ f = \rm id$

$$g_1(t) = t(1-g_2(t))$$

and also

$$1=g_1(t)^2 + g_2(t)^2= t^2(1-2g_2(t)+g_2(t)^2) + g_2^2(t)$$

hence

$$g_2(t)= \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

and

$$g_1(t)= t-t\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

giving your inverse $g(t)$.